Convergence by subsequence
Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $X$ and let $x\in X$. If every subsequence of $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ admits a subsequence that converges to $x$, prove that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $x$.
My attempt:
We need to prove that given an open $U\subset X$, with $x\in U$, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geqslant n_0$ we have $x_n\in U$.
In fact, let $U\ni x$ be open. By hypothesis, $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ such that there exists an open $V\subset U$ and $n_k\geqslant n_0$ such that $x_{n_k}\in V$.
Now consider the subsequence $(x_{nj})_{j=1}^\infty$ formed by the elements $x_n$ without the elements $x_{nk}$. Hypothetically, there exists a subsequence $(x_{nz})_{z=1}^\infty$ of $(x_{nj})_{j=1}^\infty$ such that it converges to $x$. Construct a new subsequence $(x_{nv})_{v=1}^\infty$ formed by the elements $x_{nj}$ without the elements $x_{nz}$.
But I don't know how continue. This construction is complicated because it is not possible to take a min$\{n_0,n_1,\ldots\}$
EDIT (my new attempt)
Suppose $x_n\not\longrightarrow x$, then there exists an open $U\ni x$ such that given $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ there are infinity-valued $x_k$, $k\geqslant n_0$, such that $x_k\not\in U$. If this were the case, then consider a subsequence of $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ formed by the elements $x_k$ such that $x_k\not\in U$, that is, $(x_k)_{k\geqslant n_0}^\infty$ with $x_k\not\in U$. Note that by hypothesis, this subsequence must have a subsequence converging to $x$, that is, there must be a subsequence $(x_{k_i})_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $x_{k_i}\in U$ for $k_i\geqslant m_0$, for some $m_0\in\mathbb{N}$. Absurd! Here is the result.

Argue by contradiction instead. What if $x_n$ doesn't converge to $x$? Then there exists an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ and a subsequence $x_{n_k}\notin V$ for all $k$. This further has a subsequence which has a limit $x$ necessarily in $X\setminus V$ since its closed. So it cannot possibly happen since $x\in V$

Your approach seems like you are trying to be constructive - I don't think this is possible for this particular theorem.

@Jakobian thanks for tip, I believe that my new attempt would be correct now.

Edit (see comments) : in the case $X$ is a subset or $\mathbb R$ then we can use the monotonicity argument as an alternative proof. this unfortunately doesn't generalize well in other spaces ($\mathbb C$ for instance, but even $\mathbb R^n$ already).
Let consider the particular subsequences $\begin{cases}v_n=\sup\{x_k\mid k\ge n\}\\w_n=\inf\{x_k\mid k\ge n\}\end{cases}$ associated to $\varlimsup$ and $\varliminf$.
They are both monotonic ($v_n\searrow$ and $w_n\nearrow$) therefore since they admit a convergent subsequence to $x$ then they themselves converge to $x$
e.g. see this post Let ($x_n$) be a monotone sequence and contain a convergent subsequence. Prove that ($x_n$) is convergent.
Ultimately $\varliminf x_n=\varlimsup x_n=x\implies x_n\to x$

sup and inf isn't only for real scalars?

you are right, I just didn't pay attention the wording was for a general space.  anyway for the real case, this is a possible alternative proof.

Direct Proof:
Suppose every subsequence has a subsequence converging to $x$. Let $U$ be an open set containing $x$. The closed set $U^c$ does not contain any sequence converging to $x$, hence it does not contain any sequence containing a subsequence converging to $x$, hence it does not contain any subsequence of $(x_n)_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$. Consequently, $I=\{n\in{\mathbb N}, x_n\in U^c\}$ is finite. For every $n\gt \max I$, one has $x_n\in U$. This proves that $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$.
Proof by contraposition:  Suppose $(x_n)$ does not converge to $x$. There is an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that for every $N\in {\mathbb N}$, there exists $k_N \ge N$ such that $x_{k_N}\not \in U$. For $N\ge 1$ one can choose $k_N\gt \max(N, k_{N-1})$ so that the sequence $N\rightarrow k_N$ increases strictly.
Now the subsequence $(x_{k_N})_N$ is included into $U^c$ which is closed, hence none of its subsequences converges to $x\in U$.
